# Vuefire Firestore Set Data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I am trying to have vuefire set component data using the following code:

```
<script>
import { db } from "../../firebase/firestore";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newComment: {
        content: ""
      },
      comments: []
    };
  },
  firestore: {
    comments: db.collection("tester")
  },
</script>
```

However, the comments data array is never filled.
I know that the firestore database is being reached because my usage stats are climbing every time I refresh the page.
Anybody know how to get this working?

Comment: The code you're showing here is not actually querying Firestore.  `db.collection("tester")` just creates a CollectionReference object, and does not read or write anything.

Comment: Holy cow.  From what I read here: https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#declarative-binding , it seems to suggest it is reading.  Any suggestion for how to read whilst keeping subscribed to any changes to collection?

Comment: Didn't realize vue has a declarative binding.  Not sure what's going wrong then.

Comment: While this is indeed according to the VueFire docs, I'm having a hard time figuring out how VueFire is binding in this snippet. The `$bind` syntax they also document [here](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#declarative-binding) seems more common to me, so it might be worth trying that (first): `this.$bind('comments', db.collection('tester'))`.

Comment: Thank you! That is getting me on the right track.  Now getting error stating insufficient permissions.  How might I configure that to permit my app to get the data?

Comment: Since I was already enforcing authentication prior to accessing any read/write, I set up the firestore rule permit read/write if the auth was not null.  That should be sufficient given the database doesn't need to be secure anyway.  Your suggestion of suing the $bind option did solve my problem.  I also discovered that the firestore plugin file the docs have you create needs to be imported into the main.js file prior to creating the vue instance.  Probably a small oversight on my part there.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for help.
The docs don't explicitly tell you to import the plugin file into your Main.js file (where you create the Vue instance).  This is essential and allows the usage of $bind in any of your components.
From there I used Frank Van Puffelen's suggestion in a created() hook to set the local data.
Also look into your firestore's rule to make sure you are allowing read or write requests.